# Database connection in WCF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

There is WCF Client (from excel connected to service via dll), 
The server code connnects to database via singelton, if the number of clients increase , does the DB Connection pooling automatically work(DB is SQLServer),

if it does not use connection pooling, how to ensure each WCF Client can have its own database connection, and it will be used only needed.

Comment: Just how many clients are we talking about here?  Generally providing a dedicated database connection per concurrent client doesn't scale in the same way as a dedicated thread per client.

Comment: How do  you host your WCF server?   If it's IIS, then IIS has a default number of concurrent requests

Comment: it is hosted in IIS.